# Remote QuickBooks functionality API?

Tags: saas, quickbooks

Is there an API for using QuickBooks functionality, not merely the data of QuickBooks users, remotely from my own SaaS application?

Comment: You might get some better information if you explained more about why you want to do what you want to do... it's a pretty strange request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

If you install an application that uses the [QuickBooks SDK](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0085_QuickBooks_Windows_SDK/010_qb) on the same machine that's running QuickBooks, you have a limited ability to interact with the QuickBooks UI: you can create a menu item on the QuickBooks menu, respond to data events, and cause QuickBooks to display reports and individual transactions. It would not be realistic to try to control QuickBooks from a Saas application using this configuration.

If you use the [Intuit Partner Platform](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform), which is a good way to integrate a Saas application, you are working with data only.

Answer (score 0):

The following content is intended to demonstrate INTUIT API AUTHORIZATION in a simplified way:

Note: This tutorial assumes that you have already registered in https://developer.intuit.com
and created and and registered new app. So you must be having 'Oauth Consumer Key' & 'Oauth Consumer Secret'.

Outlined Steps:

```
Get REQUEST TOKEN, REQUEST TOKEN SECRET & Authorization URL.

Go to Authorization URL select the company to be authorised and click Authorize button.

Get OAUTH VERIFIER CODE post authorization (after autorization button is clicked) through a GET request from Intuit API server.

Get ACCESS TOKEN and ACCESS TOKEN SECRET using
OAUTH VERIFIER CODE,
REQUEST TOKEN & REQUEST TOKEN SECRET.

Create DateService object using 'Oauth Consumer Key', 'Oauth Consumer Secret', ACCESS TOKEN, ACCESS TOKEN SECRET & Company id (a.k.a Realm id).
```

http://philosophyofsciencetech.blogspot.in/2016/04/intuit-java-api-authorization-java-to.html